# How can I simulate a PHP preg_replace in C#?

Tags: c#

I am converting code from PHP to C# and need to convert this code:

```
 $str = preg_replace('/[っッ](.)/u', '${1}${1}', $str);
```

Is there something like preg_replace in C# that I could use.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at Regex.Replace in .NET

Comment: Have you done any research on how to do this? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). There are minor difference in regex syntax, but mostly it will be a copy/paste thing.

For example, the following PHP stuff:

```
$str = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

can be done in C# like:

```
var str = "April 15, 2003";
var pattern = "^(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)$";
var replacement = "$1";
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacement, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
string input = "your str value" ;
string pattern = "[っッ](.)";
string replacement = "$1$1";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: This doesn't say how to access the Regex class

Answer (score 0):

You can write function like this:

```
    public static string PregReplace(string pattern, string newValue, string src)
    {
        Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
        MatchCollection mc = rg.Matches(src);
        foreach (var match in mc)
        {
            src = src.Replace(match.ToString(), newValue);
        }
        return src;
    }
```

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Regex.Replace() can do this with iterating through `MatchCollection`s.

Comment: PHP and C# are vastly different languages. Please do not try to force one to behave like the other. If you translate natural languages word by word, the native speakers will perceive you as weird. The same applies to programming lamguages

Comment: @dotNET,@Suppen the question was "How can I simulate a PHP preg_replace in C#?" i wrote the function to simulate it.

Comment: @S.Petrosov: There are endless ways of achieving correct output for any given problem. A good programmers tries to write small/readable code and take advantage of the functionality available in the base libraries.